# I have a single switch for ceiling fan/light. I want to replace it with a single split switch that operates both independently. How do I wire it?

Tags: switch

[image][image][image][image: I have a single switch for ceiling fan and overhead light. I want to replace it with a single split switch that operates both independently. The wires coming from the current switch are different than the wires coming from the new independent switch. I don't know how to wire it. Any help would be appreciated. [![enter image description her]e][5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wTNc.jpg)][5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wTNc.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92Hpu.jpg)

Comment: Pictures of the wires on the old switch with the breaker turned off.  I imagine you just have one wire on each screw of the the switch, so you probably will need a new cable from the switch to the fan.

Comment: Pictures uploaded as edit to original question. Thank you.

Comment: It's worth noting that not all ceiling fans are compatible with such a switch and you should make sure that yours is.

Comment: Well, seems that may have been a good response.  I just looked it up online and it says I can't use a dimmer style.  Will have to find one with stationary switches only but no dimmer it seems.  This is a Lutron Skylark light/fan control with dimmer switch.  Thank you for that info.  I had no idea to check for something like this.

Comment: Except: The warning about dimmer specifically is often so that you do *not* use a dimmer for the **fan**. Which you definitely should not do. If you can indeed control fan and light separately then you can nearly always dim the **light**. While conceptually a fan motor speed control and light dimming are the same, technically they are quite different. **Fan/light model # please!**

Comment: It is beginning to sound like I just need to call an electrician.  Most likely need to run a new wire to do what I am wanting. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a job for a "remote kit". There are three ways to control a combination fan and light separately:

- Wall switch for both together, pull chains for fan and light separately. That's the old way of doing things.
- Double wall switch. That's what you are trying to do. The problem is that it needs separate wires for fan and light. As far as I can tell, you don't have the extra wire you need.
- Remote control.

With a remote control kit, one box gets installed above the fan/light. It connects to your existing fan and light and your existing switch wires/cable. You can then use the wall switch to turn everything on/off (usually) but most of the time you use a wireless remote, typically stored in a holder on the wall right next to your regular switch. I don't like these things and don't recommend them for new installations. However, for a retrofit installation they can be a good solution *if your fan/light is compatible*.

The alternative is to run a new cable (black/white/red/ground) from your switch box to the fan/light. That is generally going to be a *lot* more work than installing a remote kit.

Comment: Yes, it is currently operated by a mail wall switch and then pull chains for the light and fan.  I just cant reach them well because of where my bed is.  And I can't move the bed.  So......I call in the pros to help me.  Thank you so much for all your information.